# Descomposición en factores primos. ¿Como optimizo o mejoro mi codigo?

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber cómo podría mejorar mi código *Javascript*, es referente a la descomposición de números en factores primos.

Por el momento, es funcional para cualquier entero positivo.

Está compuesto por tres funciones que cumplen con distintas tareas (descritas en el código)

Las cuales son: obtener los divisores, obtener los números primos divisores del número ingresado, por último, generar una lista con los factores primos del número.

Muestra los factores primos separados por `x`.

```js
function divisores(numero) {
  let divisores = new Array(); // Arreglo que alberga los divisores
  for (let i = 1; i <= numero; i++) {
    if ((numero % i) === 0) { // Si modulo de i nos da 0 es un divisor
      divisores.push(i);
    }
  }
  return divisores; // retornamos la lista de divisores
}

function numeros_primos(numero) {
  const list_divisores = divisores(numero); // Almacena la lista de divisores en otra varible
  let primos = new Array(), // Almacena los numeros primos que dividen al numero
    contador = 0; // Contador de divisores. Si los divisores de un numeros son 2. Es primo.
  for (let numeros of list_divisores) { //Intera los divisores del numero.
    for (let j = 1; j <= (numeros + 1); j++) {
      if ((numeros % j) === 0) { // Cuenta el numero de divisores que tiene cada numero.
        contador += 1
      }
    }
    if (contador === 2) { // Si es igual a dos. Se agrega el valor a el array primos
      primos.push(numeros);
      contador = 0;

    } else if (contador === 1 || contador > 2) { // Si contador === 1. Significa que es el numero 1, ya que el 1 solo tiene un divisor, el 1.
      contador = 0; // Se reinicia el contador
    }
  }
  return primos; // Retorna la lista con los numeros primos divisores
}

function factores_primos(numero) {
  const primos = numeros_primos(numero); //Se almacena numeros primos en un constante.
  let factores_primos = [1]; // El 1 es factor primo de todos los numeros. Por eso se agrega a la lista.
  while (numero > 1) {
    for (let factores of primos) {
      if ((numero % factores) === 0) {
        numero = numero / factores; // Divide el numero hasta que sea igual a 1.
        factores_primos.push(factores); // Agregar el factor divisor a factores_primos.
        break; // Termina la interación para dividir de nuevo el numero por todos los divisores primos

      }
    }
  }
  return factores_primos; // Devuelve los factores primos en una lista.
}

let numero = 1340, //parseInt(prompt("Digite el numero que desea descomponer: "));
  factores = factores_primos(numero); // Se almacena los factores primos en una variable.

factores = factores.join(" x ");
console.log("Los factores primos del numero " + numero + " son: " + "(" + factores + ")");
```

Comment: ¿En qué aspectos quieres mejorar tu código? ¿Velocidad o estilo?

Answer (score 0):

No mejoré el código, pero escribí uno nuevo que me parece más adecuado.

```html
<body>
    <button onclick="calculate()">Calcular</button>
    <table id="table">
    </table>

    <script>
        function isPrime(num){
            for(let i=2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++){
                if(num % i === 0){
                    return false
                }
            }
            return true
        }

        function PrimeFactors(num){
            let factors = []

            while(true){
                let has_factor = false

                for(let i = 2;i <= Math.sqrt(num);i++){
                    if(num % i === 0 && isPrime(i)){
                        num /= i
                        factors.push(i)
                        has_factor = true
                        break
                    }
                }

                if(!has_factor){
                    factors.push(num)
                    return factors
                }

            }
        }

        function calculate(){
            let elem = document.getElementById("table")
            let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)

            elem.innerHTML = ""

            for(let factor of PrimeFactors(num)){
                let row = elem.insertRow()
                row.insertCell().innerText = num
                row.insertCell().innerText = factor
                num /= factor
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Apliqué los siguientes conceptos:

- No necesitamos conocer todos los divisores para saber si un número es primo o no, nos alcanza con obtener, si existe, el primer divisor que no sea 1 ni si mismo y parar de iterar, indicando que NO es un número primo.
- No guardar divisores en un array, ya que no necesitamos tenerlos en memoria en simultaneo.
- No existe un divisor de x mayor que la raiz cuadrada de x (además de x): (ver [esta respuesta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5811176/12913664)), por lo que nos ahorramos muchas iteraciones innecesarias.